# Android Snackbar crashes(android.view.InflateException) with enabled Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

In the Firebase, I start receiving these stack traces:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #1 in {my_project_package_name}:layout/mtrl_layout_snackbar_include: Binary XML file line #1 in {my_project_package_name}:layout/mtrl_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class x
```

The application sometimes also crashes with enabled Proguard when Snackbar is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the source code of the `mtrl_layout_snackbar_include.xml` file and found that it depends on the custom google material component:

```
class="com.google.android.material.snackbar.SnackbarContentLayout"
```

Since we have a Proguard, this class name will be changed in the compile time.

I fixed this issue by adding these rules to the Proguard to exclude this class name.

```
# Snackbar
-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.material.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.material.R$* { *; }
```